# Wget download file ( do not overwrite ) auto update script

Tags: embedded, wget

I want to write auto update script for my embedded device, which can check and download newer version of my program and extract the files on the device.
The download center is hosted on remote web server .

Script checks the hosted file on web site and if the new version is there then download it to the embedded device and extract the files in the dirs. But if the test.tar.gz is already downloaded and the files are already extracted then do nothing.

The embedded device runs Linux.

Example, this script actually does the work, but It replace the files all the time. I don't want to overwrite the files.

```
#!/bin/sh
wget http:xxx.myftp.org:2322/add/test.tar.gz
tar -zxvf test.tar.gz -C /
rm test.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a timestamp to the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
timestamp=$(date%F-%k%M)
wget http:xxx.myftp.org:2322/add/test.tar.gz -O /path/to/local/save/test.$timestamp.tar.gz
tar -zxvf test.$timestamp.tar.gz -C /
rm test.$timestamp.tar.gz
```

Adjust as needed.